# Reading list of input textFiles where individual file-names contain commas

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a folder on HDFS, which for whatever reason, contains part-files that contain commas in their name. For instance

```
hdfs://namespace/mypath/1-1,123
hdfs://namespace/mypath/1-2,124
hdfs://namespace/mypath/1-3,125
```

The issue is, I want to only read some of the part files at a time, to prevent over-loading my cluster, meaning that I want to read `1-1,123` and `1-2,124` files.

However, when path is fed to spark as:

```
sc.textFile("hdfs://namespace/mypath/1-1,123,hdfs://namespace/mypath/1-2,124")
```

Spark obviously seems to just tokenize on `","`, thereby assuming I'm looking for 4 separate files.

- Is there a way to escape the commas in the path?
- Is the only option to rename the source files?

Comment: Since the paths are URLs, have you tried to URL-encode the comma as `%2C`?

Comment: Unfortunately, already tried that. Didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SparkContext.textFile`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.0/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala) calls at some point [`FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(Job job, String commaSeparatedPaths)`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileInputFormat.html) which apparently simply splits on `,` the input `String` representing the comma-separated paths:

> Sets the given comma separated paths as the list of inputs for the map-reduce job.

One way to bypass this limitation consists in using the alternative signature of `setInputPaths`: `FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(Job job, Path... inputPaths)` which takes a `vararg` of [`Path`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/Path.html) objects. This way, no need to split on `,` and thus no confusion possible.

To do that, we'll have to create our own `textFile` method which does the exact same thing as `SparkContext.textFile`: calling the `HadoopRDD` object but this time using an input provided as a `List` of `String`s instead of a `String`:

```
package org.apache.spark

import org.apache.spark.rdd.{RDD, HadoopRDD}
import org.apache.spark.util.SerializableConfiguration
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.{FileInputFormat, JobConf, TextInputFormat}
import org.apache.hadoop.io.{LongWritable, Text}
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path

object TextFileOverwrite {

  implicit class SparkContextExtension(val sc: SparkContext) extends AnyVal {

    def textFile(
        paths: Seq[String],
        minPartitions: Int = sc.defaultMinPartitions
    ): RDD[String] = {

      val confBroadcast =
        sc.broadcast(new SerializableConfiguration(sc.hadoopConfiguration))

      val setInputPathsFunc =
        (jobConf: JobConf) =>
          FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(jobConf, paths.map(p => new Path(p)): _*)

      new HadoopRDD(
        sc,
        confBroadcast,
        Some(setInputPathsFunc),
        classOf[TextInputFormat],
        classOf[LongWritable],
        classOf[Text],
        minPartitions
      ).map(pair => pair._2.toString)
    }
  }
}
```

which can be used this way:

```
import org.apache.spark.TextFileOverwrite.SparkContextExtension

sc.textFile(Seq("path/hello,world.txt", "path/hello_world.txt"))
```

---

Compared to `SparkContext.textFile`, the only difference in the implementation is the call to `FileInputFormat.setInputPaths` which takes `Path`s in input instead of a comma-separated `String`.

Note that I use the package `org.apache.spark` to store this function, because `SerializableConfiguration` has the visibility `private[spark]` in spark's code base.

Also note the use of an `implicit class` on `SparkContext` which allows us to implicitly attach this additional `textFile` method directly to the `SparkContext` object and thus to call it using `sc.textFile()` instead of having to pass the `sparkContext` as a parameter of the method.

Also note that I would have preferred giving `Seq[Path]` instead of `Seq[String]` as an input of this method, but `Path` is not yet `Serializable` in the current version of `hadoop-common` used by Spark (it will become `Serializable` starting version 3 of `hadoop-common`).

Comment: This works, thanks. As an aside however, it's rather sad that a rather convoluted approach has to be taken to overcome this rather simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use filename globbing, assuming that this gives you unique files:

```
sc.textFile("hdfs://namespace/mypath/1-1?123,hdfs://namespace/mypath/1-2?124")
```

Doesn't work if you only want the first one of these and not the other two:

```
hdfs://namespace/mypath/1-1,123,hdfs
hdfs://namespace/mypath/1-1:123,hdfs
hdfs://namespace/mypath/1-1.123,hdfs
```

I was going to suggest this:

```
sc.textFile("hdfs://namespace/mypath/1-1[,]123, ...
```

And I think that's supposed to work.  Looking at the code for `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat#getPathStrings` though makes me suspicious.  It looks like that function specifically looks for commas inside curly braces, and will fail if you put a comma inside [,].